# updating/ refreshing the controls which are in Rad ajax panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am facing problem in updating/ refreshing the controls which are in Rad ajax panel .

I have a Rad ajax panel in which i have placed a grid, and RadPanelBar side to side by placing them in table.

when the user selects any record in grid the details of that record will be shown in it's beside RadPanelBar. So 
in this process of selecting records i am refreshing the Entire Rad ajax panel for getting the correct selected record details.

But additionally what i want is when the user sorts the records of grid i need to refresh the grid only , for this i placed 
Radgrid again in other radajaxpanel which is creating the problems. My Radgrid is not getting updated with the click events of grid, when i click on link button of grid
it should highlight the clicked row. But when i placed grid in Ajax panel it is not getting highlighted untill unleass i refresh the Grid.
when i placed it in another nested rad ajax panel. Please help me how can i achieve refreshing the only the Radgrid while sorting?

My design:

```
<telerik:RadPageView ID="radPage1" runat="server">
                    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel3" runat="server" EnableAJAX="True" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"
                        ClientEvents-OnRequestStart="onRequestStart">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 50%">
                              <%-- <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel4" runat="server" EnableAJAX="True" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"
                               ClientEvents-OnRequestStart="onRequestStart"> --%>

                                   <telerik:RadGrid ID="radGrid" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="False"
                                        OnNeedDataSource="grdUnResolvedFaxes_NeedDataSource" Skin="Metro" CellSpacing="0"
                                        GridLines="None" Width="99%" PageSize="12" OnItemCommand="grdUnResolvedFaxes_ItemCommand"
                                        EnableViewState="true">....
                                         .....
                                         .....
                                  </telerik:RadGrid>

                             <%-- </telerik:RadAjaxPanel> --%>

                                </td>

                              <td style="width: 50%">
                                 <telerik:RadPanelBar runat="server" ID="pnlBar" ExpandMode="MultipleExpandedItems"
                                        Width="99%" Visible="false">
                                 <Items>
                             .................
                                 </Items>
                                  </telerik:RadPanelBar>
                               </td>
                              </tr>
                        </table>
                 </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>

              </telerik:RadPageView>
```

For the Linkbutton click of the grid i added below code to update the grid

```
  if (e.CommandName.ToLower() == "select")
     { 
                    RadAjaxPanel4.ResponseScripts.Add(String.Format("$find('{0}').ajaxRequest();", RadAjaxPanel3.ClientID));
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what this linkbutton is, but from what I can gather, you want one action (an update on the grid) to do two different things (update the grid only, or also update the panelbar). This is quite a confusing scenario and I do not thing there is a way for the code to know when to only include one control.

Thus, you can consider using `asp:UpdatePanel` with `UpdateMode=Conditional` around the panelbar and call its `Update()` server method only when you need to rebind data in it. This can give you a conditional update there when needed. In this case, a RadAjaxPanel around the grid only should suffice.

Nesting AjaxPanels can cause issues as you have found, so you should avoid that.

If you know on the client that you need to update the panelbar you can show a RadAjaxLoadingPanel over its element with JavaScript as shown here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-show-hide-loadingpanel.html.